# Fetching only different data from Parse

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, fetch

I am trying to update an array of `PFObjects`. In my understanding, `fetchAll()` (in its asynchronous derivations) is the correct method to update all the objects, as `fetchAllIfNeeded()` will only update the `PFObjects` that have no data associated with them yet. However each time `fetchAll()` is executed, the entire list of `PFObjects` is downloaded again, whether or not any change has been made. For example, if I have a list of posts, and I would like to check if any edits to the posts has been made, in every case all the posts in their entirety, (text, pictures and so on) will be downloaded, regardless of whether the text of one post was simply edited or even if there were any edits at all. There is a big difference in data consumption in downloading the text for one attribute of a `PFObject` and downloading a whole array of them, many including pictures, and so I would like to find a method that will only download the changes. Is this possible?

In addition, if this is possible, is there a way that I could get a list of the `PFObjects` that needed updating? i.e., if posts 4 and 12 needed updating out of an array of 20, how could I know this?

Thanks.

Comment: fetchAll does as it's name implies - fetches all objects.  You can use a PFQuery against the `updatedAt` column to retrieve objects that have been updated since a certain date/time. You will need to keep track of your update date/time locally

Comment: But is there any way to download only objects that have been changed server side?

Comment: Yes, issue a PFQuery for objects with an `updatedAt` time after the last time you checked.  The response will be the objects that have been updated.

Comment: Oh. I understand now. Thanks. If you add this as an answer I can mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fetchAll does as it's name implies - fetches all objects. You can use a PFQuery against the updatedAt column to retrieve objects that have been updated since a certain date/time. You will need to keep track of your last update date/time locally, say using NSUserDefaults -

```
let query=PFQuery.queryWithclassName("MyClass")

let defaults=NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

if let lastUpdateDate=defaults.objectForKey("lastUpdateDate") as? NSDate {
    q.whereKey("updatedAt",greaterThan:lastUpdateDate)
}

q.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({(objects:[AnyObject]!, error: NSError!) in
        if(error == nil) {

            defaults.setObject(NSDate(),forKey:"lastUpdateDate") 

            for object in objects {
              ...
            }
        } else {
            //Do something with error
        }
})
```

Comment: @Acoop Note, I initially had `lessThan`, this should be `greaterThan`